# Прерывание выполнения метода "А" на время выполнения метода "Б"

Tags: c#, asp.net

Доброго времени суток. Пытаюсь реализовать очередь на отправку сообщений. Имеется две очереди (напр. ConcurrentQueue). Одна будет хранить в себе обычные сообщения, другая - важные. В основном будет использоваться обычная очередь. Отправка сообщений происходит в ParallelForeach. Но если в "Важной" очереди появились сообщения необходимо прервать отправку сообщений из главной очереди, отправить важные, а за тем возобновить стандартную. Т.е. прервать выполнение метода на время выполнения другого и после вернуть управление первому. Спасибо.

P.S. Первое что пришло на ум это CancellationToken. Но может есть какие-то более простые и удобные варианты варианты.

Comment: Такое ощущение, что метод должен сам брать из нужной очереди...

Comment: Извините. Не уточнил. Конечно будет метод, который будет следить за очередью, доставать из неё данные (по мере их поступления) и передовать их в метод отправления.

Comment: Ну сделайте вы свой класс, в котором спрячете две очереди, а в методе Dequeue напишите типа: `return criticalQueue.Count > 0 ? criticalQueue.Dequeue() : normalQueue.Dequeue();` в чем проблема-то?

Comment: Спасибо Вам, Андрей. Это интересное решение.

Comment: Отправка сообщений через Parallel.Foreach? Вы делаете что-то не то.  Отправка должна быть быстрой, зачем там многопоточность?

Comment: Отправка сообщения процесс не быстрый. Тем более, если сразу прилетело 100 000 сообщений. По этому я выбрал этот инструмент. Почему Вы считаете что это плохой выбор. И что Вы предложите вмето него.

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам могут помочь функции-генераторы, я слышал такие есть в C#. Сам пишу на js, где они также есть и по сути они могут приостанавливать выполнение функции на необходимое время, а потом возобновлять выполнение с момента остановки.

[Вот посмотрите здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield)